# Unable to perfectly implement QuickSort

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I am trying to write a simple method in java that would perform quicksort on an int[] but I keep getting one value that is out of place in my results.

Any help to understand where I am going wrong would be appreciated. Below is my code:

```
public static void quickSort(int[] arr, int left, int right){
    if (left < right){
        int p = partition(arr, left, right);
        quickSort(arr, left, p-1);
        quickSort(arr, p+1, right);
    }
}

public static int partition(int[] arr, int left, int right){
    int pivot = arr[left];
    int l = left+1;
    int r = right;
    while (l < r){
        while (l<right && arr[l] < pivot){
            l++;
        }
        while (r>left && arr[r] > pivot){
            r--;
        }
        if (l < r){
            int temp = arr[l];
            arr[l] = arr[r];
            arr[r] = temp;
        }
    }
    arr[left] = arr[r];
    arr[r] = pivot;         
    return r;
}
```

Comment: What if `right` equals `left+1`? The two elements get exchanged without any key comparison. (Oh, and the comparison `r>left` is redundant if the pivot remains in `arr[left]` until after the loop.)

Answer (score 0):

your code is perfect but be sure to give the right values to method quickSort.

```
        int[] arr = .....;
        int left = 0;
        int right = arr.length - 1;

  public static void quickSort(int[] arr, int left, int right){
```

Comment: That is exactly what I'm providing as parameters.

Answer (score 0):

These two lines are suspicious:

`quickSort(arr, p+1, right);`

and

`int l = left+1;`

When taking the right side partition, are you skipping the first element of the array? Some example test cases and their output would be useful to add.

Comment: As far as I can understand, I am not skipping any of the values. As I used the debugger, I also noticed that it initially sorts it correct and then switches them again. At least in the second test case.

This is one test case that I tried:
Input Array: 8 5 9 10 12 9 6 12 13 19 22 14 17 21 5 1 4 3 2 
Result: 1 2 3 4 5 5 6 8 9 9 10 12 12 13 17 14 19 21 22

A second test case:
Input Array: 8 5 9 10 12 7 6 13 19 22 14 17 21 5 1 4 3 2 
Result: 1 2 3 4 5 5 7 6 8 9 10 12 13 14 17 19 21 22

Answer (score 0):

I changed your partition method. I try to do minor changes, mostly for breaking the loop.

```
public static int partition(int[] arr, int left, int right) {
    int pivot = arr[left];
    int l = left ;
    int r = right+1;
    while (true) {
        while (arr[++l] < pivot) {
            if (l >= right)
                break;
        }
        while (arr[--r] > pivot) {
            if (r <= left)
                break;
        }
        if (l >= r)
            break;
        int temp = arr[l];
        arr[l] = arr[r];
        arr[r] = temp;
    }
    arr[left] = arr[r];
    arr[r] = pivot;
    return r;
}
```

I tested for below scenarios and it is working.

```
int[] arr = { 9, 5, 10, 8, 2, 3, 4, 7, 6, 1 };
int[] arr = { 9, 5, 10, 8, 2, 9, 5, 10, 8, 2 };
quickSort(arr, 0, arr.length - 1);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

Comment: Thank you for that. I'm unable to understand why that would make the difference but I'll try to implement that in my code and see if it does it.

Comment: Adding the break statements to get out of the while loop seems to do it. Not sure why that is the case though.

Comment: the previous code could not check for border conditions, when to break or continue. the three break statements are just doing this. previous code is doing both value checks and border checks, but the new code is checking values for validity, and then checks borders to break or continue.

Comment: @rcgldr i changed the break statements, can you check it. i tested for using your inputs.

Comment: @UgurBasak - I posted an answer, but I converted from C to Java. Perhaps you could test this. This is essentially the wiki [Hoare partition scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Hoare_partition_scheme).

Answer (score 0):

Hoare partition scheme uses p and p+1 in the quicksort calls. I converted a working C program to Java. I switched the pivot to the middle so sorted or reverse sorted arrays are not worst case.

```
public static void quickSort(int[] arr, int left, int right){
    if (left < right){
        int p = partition(arr, left, right);
        quickSort(arr, left, p);
        quickSort(arr, p+1, right);
    }
}

public static int partition(int[] arr, int left, int right){
    int pivot = arr[(left+right)/2];
    int l = left-1;
    int r = right+1;
    while (true){
        while (arr[++l] < pivot);
        while (arr[--r] > pivot);
        if (l >= r)
            break;
        int temp = arr[l];
        arr[l] = arr[r];
        arr[r] = temp;
        }
    }
    return r;
}
```